# Can I access an Xtreemfs both through LAN and a DDNS WAN address?

Tags: networking, dns, filesystems, ddns

Since [the user guide](http://xtreemfs.org/xtfs-guide-1.5/index.html) only mentions "dynamic networks" once without explaining or linking an explanation what that is, I'd like to know if I can use Xtreemfs on a client which access the server via a 192.168.x.x. address at home and via a dynamic DNS (DDNS) address via WAN without major configuration changes and restart of the server (which is necessary e.g. for OpenAFS).

I'd be using Xtreemfs 1.5.x on Ubuntu 17.04 on the server and client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify a fixed `listen.address` property in the configuration files for DIR, MRC or OSD, they will listen on all interfaces. See [Section 3.2.7](http://www.xtreemfs.org/xtfs-guide-1.5.1/index.html#tth_sEc3.2.7).